# How to get right MIPS libc toolchain for embedded device

Tags: linux, gcc, embedded, cross-compiling, libc

I've run into a problem (repetitively) with various company's' embedded linux products where GPL source code from them does not match what is actually running on a system.  It's "close", but not quite right, especially with respect to the standard C library they use.
Isn't that a violation of the GPL?

Often this mismatch results in a programmer (like me) cross compiling only to have the device reply cryptically "file not found" or something similar when the program is run.

I'm not alone with this kind of problem -- For many people have threads directly and indirectly related to the problem: eg:
[Compile parameters for MIPS based codesourcery toolchain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183433/compile-parameters-for-mips-based-codesourcery-toolchain)

And I've run into the problem on Sony devices, D-link, and many others.  It's very common.

Making a new library is not a good solution, since most systems are ROMFS only, and LD_LIBRARY_PATH is sometimes broken -- so that installing a new library on the device wastes very limited memory and often won't work.

If I knew what the right source code version of the library was, I could go around the manufacturer's carelessness and compile it from the original developer's tree; but how can I find out which version I need when all I have is the binary of the library itself?

For example: I ran elfread -a libc.so.0 on a DSL modem's libc (see below); but I don't see anything here that could tell me exactly which libc it was...

How can I find the name of the source code, or an identifier from the library's binary so I can create a cross compiler using that library?  eg: Can anyone tell me what source code this library came from, and how they know?

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 02 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, big endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           MIPS R3000
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x5a60
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          0 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x1007, noreorder, pic, cpic, o32, mips1
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         4
  Size of section headers:           0 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         0
  Section header string table index: 0

There are no sections in this file.

There are no sections to group in this file.

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  REGINFO        0x0000b4 0x000000b4 0x000000b4 0x00018 0x00018 R   0x4
  LOAD           0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x2c9ee 0x2c9ee R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x02c9f0 0x0006c9f0 0x0006c9f0 0x009a0 0x040b8 RW  0x1000
  DYNAMIC        0x0000cc 0x000000cc 0x000000cc 0x0579a 0x0579a RWE 0x4

Dynamic section at offset 0xcc contains 19 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000e (SONAME)                     Library soname: [libc.so.0]
 0x00000004 (HASH)                       0x18c
 0x00000005 (STRTAB)                     0x3e9c
 0x00000006 (SYMTAB)                     0x144c
 0x0000000a (STRSZ)                      6602 (bytes)
 0x0000000b (SYMENT)                     16 (bytes)
 0x00000015 (DEBUG)                      0x0
 0x00000003 (PLTGOT)                     0x6ce20
 0x00000011 (REL)                        0x5868
 0x00000012 (RELSZ)                      504 (bytes)
 0x00000013 (RELENT)                     8 (bytes)
 0x70000001 (MIPS_RLD_VERSION)           1
 0x70000005 (MIPS_FLAGS)                 NOTPOT
 0x70000006 (MIPS_BASE_ADDRESS)          0x0
 0x7000000a (MIPS_LOCAL_GOTNO)           11
 0x70000011 (MIPS_SYMTABNO)              677
 0x70000012 (MIPS_UNREFEXTNO)            17
 0x70000013 (MIPS_GOTSYM)                0x154
 0x00000000 (NULL)                       0x0

There are no relocations in this file.

The decoding of unwind sections for machine type MIPS R3000 is not currently supported.

Histogram for bucket list length (total of 521 buckets):
 Length  Number     % of total  Coverage
      0  144        ( 27.6%)
      1  181        ( 34.7%)     27.1%
      2  130        ( 25.0%)     66.0%
      3  47         (  9.0%)     87.1%
      4  12         (  2.3%)     94.3%
      5  5          (  1.0%)     98.1%
      6  1          (  0.2%)     99.0%
      7  1          (  0.2%)    100.0%

No version information found in this file.

Primary GOT:
 Canonical gp value: 00074e10

 Reserved entries:
   Address     Access  Initial Purpose
  0006ce20 -32752(gp) 00000000 Lazy resolver
  0006ce24 -32748(gp) 80000000 Module pointer (GNU extension)

 Local entries:
   Address     Access  Initial
  0006ce28 -32744(gp) 00070000
  0006ce2c -32740(gp) 00030000
  0006ce30 -32736(gp) 00000000
  0006ce34 -32732(gp) 00010000
  0006ce38 -32728(gp) 0006d810
  0006ce3c -32724(gp) 0006d814
  0006ce40 -32720(gp) 00020000
  0006ce44 -32716(gp) 00000000
  0006ce48 -32712(gp) 00000000

 Global entries:
   Address     Access  Initial Sym.Val. Type    Ndx Name
  0006ce4c -32708(gp) 000186c0 000186c0 FUNC    bad section index[  6] __fputc_unlocked
  0006ce50 -32704(gp) 000211a4 000211a4 FUNC    bad section index[  6] sigprocmask
  0006ce54 -32700(gp) 0001e2b4 0001e2b4 FUNC    bad section index[  6] free
  0006ce58 -32696(gp) 00026940 00026940 FUNC    bad section index[  6] raise
  ...
  truncated listing
  ....
```

---

Note:
The rest of this post is a blog showing how I came to ask the question above and to put useful information about the subject in one place.
Don't bother reading it unless you want to know I actually did research the question... in gory detail... and how NOT to answer my question.

The proper (theoretical) way to get a libc program running on (for example) a D-link modem would simply be to get the *TRUE* source code for the product from the manufacturer, and compile against those libraries....  (It's GPL !? right, so the law is on our side, right?)

For example: I just bought a D-Link DSL-520B modem and a 526B modem -- but found out after the fact that the manufacturer "forgot" to supply linux source code for the 520B but does have it for the 526B.  I checked all of the DSL-5xxB devices online for source code & toolchains, finding to my delight that ALL of them (including 526B) -- contain the SAME pre-compiled libc.so.0 with MD5sum of 6ed709113ce615e9f170aafa0eac04a6 . So in theory, all supported modems in the DSL-5xxB family seemed to use the same libc library... and I hoped I might be able to use that library.

But after I figured out how to get the DSL modem itself to send me a copy of the installed /lib/libc.so.0 library -- I found to my disgust that they ALL use a library with MD5 sum of b8d492decc8207e724a0822641205078 .  In NEITHER of the modems I bought (supported or not) was found the same library as contained in the source code toolchain.

To verify the toolchain from D-link was defective, I didn't compile a program (the toolchain wouldn't run on my PC anyway as it was the wrong binary format) -- but I found the toolchain had some pre-compiled mips binaries in it already; so I simply downloaded one to the modem and chmod +x -- and (surprise) I got the message "file not found." when I tried to run it ... It won't run.

So, I knew the toolchains were no good immediately, but not exactly why.

I decided to get a newer verson of MIPS GCC (binary version) that should have less bugs, more features and which is supported on most PC platforms.  This is the way to GO!

See: [Kernel.org pre-compiled binaries](https://www.kernel.org/pub/tools/crosstool/)

I upgraded to gcc 4.9.0 after selecting the older "mips" verson from the above site to get the right FTP page; and set my shells' PATH variable to the /bin directory of the cross compiler once installed.

Then I copied all the header files and libraries from the D-link source code package into the new cross compiler just to verify that it could compile D-link libc binaries.  And it did on the first try, compiling "hello world!" with no warnings or errors into a mips 32 big endian binary.

( **START EDIT:** )  @ChrisStratton points out in the comments (after this post) that my test of the toolchain is inadequate, and that using a newer GCC with an older library -- even though it links properly -- is flawed as a test.  I wish there was a way to give him points for his comments -- I've become convinced that he's right; although that makes what D-link did even a worse problem -- for there's no way to know from the binaries on the modem which GCC they actually used.  The GCC used for the kernel isn't necessarily the same used in user space.

In order to test the new compiler's compatibility with the modems and also make tools so I could get a copy of the actual libraries found on the modem: ( **END EDIT** )  I wrote a program that doesn't use the C library at all (but in two parts): It ran just fine... and the code is attached to show how it can be done.

The first listing is an assembly language program to bypass linking the standard C libraries on MIPS; and the second listing is a program meant to create an octal number dump of a binary file/stream using only the linux kernel.  eg: It enables copying/pasting or scripting of binary data over telnet, netcat, etc... via ash/bash or busybox :) like a poor man's uucp.

```
// substart.S  MIPS assembly language bypass of libc startup code       
// it just calls main, and then jumps to the exit function       

            .text                                                               
            .globl __start                                                      
__start:    .ent    __start                                                     
            .frame  $29, 32, $31                                                
            .set noreorder                                                       
            .cpload $25                                                         
            .set reorder                                                        
            .cprestore 16                                                       

            jal main                                                            
            j   exit                                                            

            .end    __start                                                     
// end substart.S
```

...and...

```
// octdump.c
// To compile w/o libc :                                                                   
// mips-linux-gcc stubstart.S octdump.c -nostdlib -o octdump

// To compile with working libc (eg: x86 system) :
// gcc octdump.c -o octdump_x86         

#include <syscall.h>                                                            
#include <errno.h>                                                              
#include <sys/types.h>                                                          

int* __errno_location(void) { return &errno; }                                  

#ifdef _syscall1
// define three unix functions (exit,read,write) in terms of unix syscall macros.
_syscall1( void, exit, int, status );                                           
_syscall3( ssize_t, read, int, fd, void*, buf, size_t, count );                 
_syscall3( ssize_t, write, int, fd, const void*, buf, size_t, count );          
#endif                

#include <unistd.h>                                                             

void oct( unsigned char c ) {                                                   
    unsigned int n = c;                                                         
    int m=6;                                                                    
    static unsigned char oval[6]={'\\','\\','0','0','0','0'};                   
    if (n < 64) { m-=1; n <<= 3; }                                              
    if (n < 64) { m-=1; n <<= 3; }                                              
    if (n < 64) { m-=1; n <<= 3; }                                              

    oval[5]='0'+(n&7);                                                          
    oval[4]='0'+((n>>3)&7);                                                     
    oval[3]='0'+((n>>6)&7);                                                     
    write( STDOUT_FILENO, oval, m );                                            
}                                                              

int main(void) {                                                                
    char buffer[255];                                                           
    int count=1;                                                                
    int i;                                                                      

    while (count>0) {                                                           
        count=read( STDIN_FILENO, buffer, 17 );                                 
        if (count>0) write( STDOUT_FILENO, "echo -ne $'",11 );                  
        for (i=0; i<count; ++i) oct( buffer[i] );                               
        if (count>0) write( STDOUT_FILENO, "'\n", 2 );                          
    }                                                                           
    write( STDOUT_FILENO,"#\n",2);                                              
    return 0;                                                                   
}
```

Once mips' octdump was saved (chmod +x) as /var/octdump on the modem, it ran without errors.
(use your imagination about how I got it on there... Dlink's TFTP, & friends are broken.)

I was able to use octdump to copy all the dynamic libraries off the DSL modem and examine them, using an automated script to avoid copy/pasting by hand.

```
#!/bin/env python                                                               
# octget.py                                                                     
# A program to upload a file off an embedded linux device via telnet                      
import socket                                                                   
import time                                                                     
import sys                                                                      
import string                                                                   

if len( sys.argv ) != 4 :                                                       
    raise ValueError, "Usage: octget.py IP_OF_MODEM passwd path_to_file_to_get" 

o = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )                         
o.connect((sys.argv[1],23)) # The IP address of the DSL modem.                  
time.sleep(1)                                                                   
sys.stderr.write( o.recv(1024) )                                                
o.send("admin\r\n");                                                            
time.sleep(0.1)                                                                 
sys.stderr.write( o.recv(1024) )                                                
o.send(sys.argv[2]+"\r\n")                                                      
time.sleep(0.1)                                                                 
o.send("sh\r\n")                                                                
time.sleep(0.1)                                                                 
sys.stderr.write( o.recv(1024) )                                                
o.send("cd /var\r\n")                                                           
time.sleep(0.1)                                                                 
sys.stderr.write( o.recv(1024) )                                                
o.send("./octdump.x < "+sys.argv[3]+"\r\n" );                                   
sys.stderr.write( o.recv(21) )                                                  
get="y"                                                                         
while get and not ('#' in get):                                                 
    get = o.recv(4096)                                                          
    get = get.translate( None, '\r' )                                           
    sys.stdout.write( get )                                                     
    time.sleep(0.5)                                                             
o.close()
```

The DSL520B modem had the following libraries...
libcrypt.so.0  libpsi.so libutil.so.0  ld-uClibc.so.0  libc.so.0  libdl.so.0     libpsixml.so

... and I thought I might cross compile using these libraries since (at least in theory) -- GCC could link against them; and my problem might be solved.

I made very sure to erase all the incompatible .so libraries from gcc-4.9.0/mips-linux/mips-linux/lib, but kept the generic crt..o files; then I copied the modem's libraries into the cross compiler directory.

But even though the kernel version of the source code, and the kernel version of the modem matched -- GCC found undefined symbols in the crt files.... So, either the generic crt files or the modem libraries themselves are somehow defective... and I don't know why.  Without knowing how to get the full library version of the ? ucLibc ?  library, I'm not sure how I can get the CORRECT source code to recompile the libraries and the crt's from scratch.

Comment: Vendors dropping the ball like this is a major issue.  I wonder though, before worrying about the exact *source* if you should be worrying more about build settings.  In effect, I'd be tempted to try to make a simple program which uses just one dynamic library function and get that to work.  Perhaps you could do this by duplicating whatever the smallest executable on the device is - ideally one for which you have the source.  Also, I'm not sure it's a given that a random binary found in a compiler build should be expected to work on an embedded target.  You might try their compiler in a VM.

Comment: Hi @Chris.  OK, I'll try that; It'll take some work to get a VM up on my system; but if it does work, then that would mean that the newer GCC produced a bad executable without errors, when linking against the libc contained in the vendor's toolchain.  Do you have any idea why that might happen? eg:as I already compiled "hello world" using gcc 4.9.0 after installing the glibc from the vendor's toolchain into gcc 4.9.0.

Comment: "Without errors" is almost meaningless when the question is "does my toolchain match the system".

Comment: @Chris, The new toolchain does compile unix binaries that run on the modems -- so the new 'c' compiler does realistically match the system OS & C conventions -- it just doesn't work with libc library; I thought that by copying all the crt??.o files and libraries from the vendor's toolchain into the new compiler, that the 'c-system' would be guaranteed to be matched.  So, where am I going wrong in my thinking? Is there some documentation I need to re-read on gcc?

Comment: No, working on *other* modems says little about it being matched to the one you need it for.  There are many details of "style" of generated code which have to match, between the compiler and libraries, and between the result and the system.

Comment: @Chris. I think I see.  FYI -- I did mean that I got gcc 4.9.0 binaries to run on the very two modems that I need it to;  I am not using any *other* modems. So -- if there's a mismatch in "style" it has to be between the new compiler and old vendor libraries, not the compiler and modem.  Binaries linked to libc don't work -- binaries not linked to libc DO work.

Comment: @Chris: OK, Got the VM up, loaded the actual library from the modem libc.so.0 to link against in the toolchain, but kept all crt's in the toolchain just as they were.  If the libraries are the same, I should be able to make "hello world" without problems because the crt's match the libc -- but instead I get an error "crt0.S: undefined reference to '__uClibc_start_main'"  ;   So, I don't see how it's possible the libc on the modems is the same as in the toolchain; they will have different bugs...?